# docker run container, how to rerun

Tags: linux, docker, virtualization, lxc

I build container with:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.xyz -t dave/xyz .
```

after that I run docker with:

```
docker run -it \
--env='LDAP_USER=uid=bot_for_git,ou=bots,dc=company,dc=org' \
--env='LDAP_PASS=' --volume=/srv/docker/xyz/data1:/data \
-p 8010:8010 -p 9989:9989 dave/xyz
```

and verified that's all ok.

what is next?

My guess, that I should run `docker ps`, take container id from there, and to run container with the same preferences (environment, port mapping, volumes mapping) I should run:

```
docker start -a container_id
```

am I right?

And what about rebuilding image, if change `Dockerfile.xyz` and rebuild dave/xyz, does container with `container_id` get
update automatically, or I should repeat `docker run -it` step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker build [...]` creates an **image**. You can see your images with `docker images`. You may give that image a specific name with the `--tag=[...]` option:

```
    docker build --tag="superuser/bestimage:latest" .
```

`docker run [...] <imageId>` takes that image and starts a **container**. You can see active containers with `docker ps` (all with `docker ps -a`). If you used the tag above, `docker run -it superuser/bestimage:latest` may be used.

When you rebuild an image, a new image with a new id is created. You may see that through `docker images`.

> does container with container_id get update automatically

**No**. In order to update your container, you must first remove the container with `docker kill <id>` and then start a new one with `docker run -it <newID>`.

Comment: what about conversation `<imageId>` -> `container_id`? I mean, as mentioned in my question, when I first use `docker run --env -p imageId`, does `docker run` arguments(env, ports, volumes) saves in `container_id` and after that I can run this container with `docker start container_id`?

Comment: What you are looking for is tagging.
Updated the answer.

Comment: You not exactly answer about container from image created and `docker start` vs `docker run`, but figure out it my self

Answer (score 3):

Your initial guess

> `docker start -a container_id`

is close but to be able to interact with the container's terminal, include the `-i` option, as follows:

```bash
docker start -ai container_id
```